# VBA, range lookup error at 9th iteration debugging?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, ms-word, range

This program is run from a .xlsx document and changes the associated .docx document, replacing the selected text between two tags. Iterations 1-8 work as intended, but halfway through the 9th iteration the range is offset by 50 characters and remains offset by 50 characters for the remaining iterations. Specifically on the 9th iteration, startPos is still correct, but stopPos is offset -50. Then on the 10th iteration startPos begins where stopPos left off, -50 characters back.

The excel sheet referenced is formatted:

- |OpenTag1|CloseTag1|toReplace|Replacement|
- |OpenTag2|CloseTag2|toReplace|Replacement|
- etc...

  Public Sub WordFindAndReplaceTEST()

  ```
    '<----------------------------- Declarations ----------------------------->
    Dim msWord As Object
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim documentText As String
    Dim firstTerm As String, secondTerm As String
    Dim toReplaceTerm As String, replacementTerm As String

    Dim masterSheet As String 'Easy editing of xlsx worksheet name
    Dim cellIterator As Integer
    Dim cellStart As Integer 'Row number that Tags start on
    Dim tag1Col As String * 1, tag2Col As String * 1, _
        toReplaceCol As String * 1, replacementCol As String * 1 'Variables that point to xlsx rows
    Dim readFilePath As String, writeFilePath As String

    Dim startPos As Long 'Stores the starting position of firstTerm
    Dim stopPos As Long 'Stores the starting position of secondTerm based on first term's location
    Dim beginPosition As Long 'The next position to search for the firstTerm
    Dim myRange As Word.Range 'Total range of the section between firstTerm and secondTerm


    '<----- Easy Variable Updating ----->
    'FilePath to read from
    readFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\ReportDoc.docx"

    'User Input for FilePath to write to (Paths directly to folder xlsx sheet is in)
    writeFilePath = InputBox("What would you like to save this file as?" _
        & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\", "Save As", "TestDocument.docx")
    If writeFilePath = "" Then Exit Sub 'Exits if user hits "Cancel"

    'Xlsx Variables
    masterSheet = "Replace Example"      'Name of the xlsx sheet to search for tags
    cellStart = 2                        'Row of the first instance of tags
    tag1Col = "A"                        'Column of the section begin tags
    tag2Col = "B"                        'Column of the section end tags
    toReplaceCol = "C"                   'Column of text that represents variable to replace
    replacementCol = "D"                 'Column of text to replace variable
    '<---------------------------------->


    '<--------------------------- Document Opening --------------------------->
    'Error catching required for opening document
    On Error Resume Next
    Set msWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If msWord Is Nothing Then
        Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Setting data values from designated xlsx cells
    cellIterator = cellStart
    With Worksheets(masterSheet)
        firstTerm = .Range(tag1Col & cellIterator).Value2
        secondTerm = .Range(tag2Col & cellIterator).Value2
        toReplaceTerm = .Range(toReplaceCol & cellIterator).Value2
        replacementTerm = .Range(replacementCol & cellIterator).Value2
    End With

    'Opening document
    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        Set doc = .Documents.Open(readFilePath)
        .Activate

        'Saving as new document
        doc.SaveAs2 Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & writeFilePath, _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault


        '<----------------------------- Rangefinding ----------------------------->
        'Repeating process until cells are empty
        Do While firstTerm <> ""

            'Resetting Variables
            startPos = 0
            stopPos = 0

                'Get all the document text and store it in a variable.
                documentText = doc.Content
                Set myRange = doc.Range 'Initializing myRange object
                beginPosition = 1 'Setting beginning position

                'Error catch begin
                On Error Resume Next

                    '<--------- Getting range ---------->
                    startPos = InStr(beginPosition, documentText, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)

                    'Issue arises here on 9th iteration
                    stopPos = InStr(startPos, documentText, secondTerm, vbTextCompare)
                    '<---------------------------------->

                'Basic error catch for invalid input
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    If Err.Number = 5 Then
                        'Immediately quits document without saving
                        'Prevents errors with rerunning the macro
                        .Quit SaveChanges:=False
                        MsgBox Err.Description & vbLf & "Make sure tags being searched for are in the document."
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        'Error catching for alternative issues
                        MsgBox Err.Description
                    End If
                End If

                'Reset Error
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Shows start/end tags compared to actual start/end position
                'MsgBox doc.Range(startPos, startPos + Len(firstTerm)) & " || " & firstTerm & _
                    vbLf & doc.Range(stopPos, stopPos + Len(secondTerm)) & " || " & secondTerm '~DL

                myRange.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=stopPos

                With myRange.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    .Text = toReplaceTerm

                    'Handles strings too long for Find
                    If Len(replacementTerm) > 250 Then
                        'User Defined
                        stringOverflow replacementTerm, toReplaceTerm, myRange, doc
                    Else
                        .Replacement.Text = replacementTerm
                    End If

                    'Formatting options
                    .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
                    .Replacement.Highlight = False

                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .MatchSoundsLike = False
                    .MatchAllWordForms = False
                    .Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
                End With

            'Iterates to next row in Excel
            cellIterator = cellIterator + 1
            With Worksheets("Replace Example")
                firstTerm = .Range(tag1Col & cellIterator).Value2
                secondTerm = .Range(tag2Col & cellIterator).Value2
                toReplaceTerm = .Range(toReplaceCol & cellIterator).Value2
                replacementTerm = .Range(replacementCol & cellIterator).Value2
            End With
        Loop
  ```

  End Sub

I have tried to reset all variables between loops, I am fairly confident that despite being a consistent offset after the 9th iteration the offset is recreated each loop, not carried over.

I have identified that the issue appears in the "Getting Range" section between the first InStr() and the second InStr(). I have checked and am confident that the issue doesn't arise from any of the strings used passing the max length, nor does it arise from the length of each section or the document as a whole.

Edit:
I tried using stopPos = InStr(beginPosition, documentText, secondTerm, vbTextCompare) to make the stopPos independant of startPos and the same issue happens in the same spot.

Comment: `is offset by 50 characters and remains offset by 50 characters for the remaining iterations.` Refer to [my latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76664750/8249058) to see if it helps. Please pay special attention to hidden text (or symbols) in Word text, such as **Fileds** and **ContentControls**, etc.

Comment: If your document contains tables there will be a mismatch between the number of characters in your string and the range. End of cell and end of row markers have a 2 character length in a string, but only occupy a single character in a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having this problem I managed to use the Find function to return the exact range in the document, whether or not there are hidden or formatting characters:

```
Private Function findTagRange(tag As String, ByVal rng As Word.Range)
With rng.Find
    .Text = tag
    .MatchCase = False
    .Execute
    If .Found Then
        findTagRange = rng.Start
    Else
        findTagRange = -1
    End If
End With
```

End Function

Answer (score 1):

Whatever value you are getting for `startPos`, there must be a match for your `firstTerm` at that position. Maybe there are multiple matches in that document, and you are expecting the 2nd match, but `InStr` is giving you the first match?

Try adding this line below the first `InStr`:

```
startPos = InStr(beginPosition, documentText, firstTerm, vbTextCompare)
debug.print Mid(documentText, (startPos - 20), (Len(firstTerm) + 40))
```

This will show you what match is being found, plus the 20 characters before / after the match.

Comment: The tags are made so I only have one of each tag per document, so I know they aren't matching in multiple places.

Comment: What do you get from the `debug.print` line?

Comment: Here's another test you can try: you suspect the problem occurs on the 9th iteration, which should be row 10 on your mastersheet. Try changing `cellStart = 2` to something else like `cellStart = 7`. Does the problem still occur on row 10 of your sheet, or on the 9th iteration of the loop?

Comment: Still haven't figured out the solution, I have found with the debug.print line that the tags are being found correctly by the InStr() functions. This leads me to believe that the problem lies with the Range designation, probably not accounting for hidden characters that are accounted for by InStr().
Edit: No tables are present in the document, so those are not causing the issue.